# Through an error using Unisharp laravel file manager

Tags: laravel-5.4

i have update laravel 5.3 to 5.4 than i got this error for using laravel filemanager package Unisharp.

> FatalErrorException in ItemsController.php line 0: Method
>   Illuminate\View\View::__toString() must not throw an exception, caught
>   ErrorException: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array  (View:
>   ProjectName\resources\views\vendor\laravel-filemanager\item.blade.php)
>   (View:
>   ProjectName\resources\views\vendor\laravel-filemanager\item.blade.php)

```
return [
        'html' => (string)view($this->getView())->with([
            'files'       => $files,
            'directories' => $directories,
            'items'       => array_merge($directories, $files)
        ]),
        'working_dir' => parent::getInternalPath($path)
    ];
```

Answer (score 0):

add in the vendor views item.blade.php in the line 0

```
<?php $file = json_decode(json_encode($file),true) ; ?>
```